# Can I directly assign an address to a pointer? If so, how to do that?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int main()
{
  int a = 2; // address is 0x7ffeefbff58c
  int *b = &a;
  std::cout << "address of a: " << b << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have my int variable a at address 0x7ffeefbff58c, but can I directly assign int* b with 0x7ffeefbff58c?

I tried int * b = 0x7ffeefbff58c; 
But there is an error says "cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'long'", so do I have to use the address of a (&a) to initialize the pointer? or there is other way to do it?

Comment: You can do that using cast, but why do you need that? Note - it is not guaranteed that `a` will be on the same address you run your program the next time.

Comment: I am with Slava. "why do you need that?" for me is short for I believe we are looking at an XY problem.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Other than `nullptr`, it is best not to initilize a pointer with any hard coded value.

Comment: @RSahu except embedded where having hardcoded address is quite normal, but this is very unlikely the OP's case

Comment: @RSahu or a number read from the datasheet for a piece of hardware

Answer (score 5):

> can I directly assign int* b with 0x7ffeefbff58c?

Technically, yes.

> If so, how to do that?

With reinterpret cast.

But do realise that there is absolutely no guarantee in general that `a` would be in the address 0x7ffeefbff58c. As such, there isn't much that you can do with such integer reinterpreted as a pointer. Doing this with a local variable would be *pointless*.

A case where interpreting integer as a pointer is useful is some embedded systems that reserve some constant memory addresses for special purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Heere is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

  int *b = (int*) 0x7ffeefbff58c;
  std::cout << "b: " << b << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

after compilation and execution you will see output:

b: 0x7ffeefbff58c